# The sum of elements in an abelian group doesn't equal 0 iff it's sylow-2 group is cyclic

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, sylow-theory

Suppose we have a finite abelian group $G$ and 
$x =  \sum\limits_{g \in G}g$ .

Prove that $x \not= 0$ $<=>$ $Sylow-2$ of G is cyclic .

---

$<=$ was easy enough, because when the $sylow$ is cyclic it has a unique element of order 2. there are no more elements of order 2 outside the $sylow$ group, so the sum equlas that element.
However, I can't seem to figure the other side. I think I need to show that there is more than 1 element of order 2 and that, those elements cancel each other in the sum, but haven't figured out how.

Comment: I think you mean $\Longleftarrow$ and I don't think that your proof is correct - or I don't understand it at all.

Comment: This is essentially [Wilson's theorem for finite Abelian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson's_theorem#Gauss.27s_generalization): The product of all elements in a finite Abelian group is either $1$ or the element of order $2$ if there is only one such element.

Comment: What is Sylow-$2$ here?

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Yeah true, fixed. I meant to say that the sum equals the single element of order 2 when the group is cyclic.

Comment: @Gray That is true. But then it should be said, I guess.

Comment: @lhf Still cant understand why there can't be 1 element of order 2 if the sylow group isn't cyclic. I understand wilson's proof, but that proof doesn't seem to work in this case

Comment: @GuidoA. The 2-sylow subgroup of G

Comment: @lhf: Want to make it an answer?